# Parsing a Blocked file and generating smaller files

Tags: shell-script, scripting, perl

I have a file like below:

```
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
1hdohdsohsoihssodhoishs
2nfdksnkdsnfsdsjndkdj
3kjdscdskndskjndndsdsdsd
5
```

Like wise I might have close to 20,000 Blocks 1 to Block 5's in a single file

I need to count the number of Blocks 1 to Block 5's and then split the file into smaller 4 files. First 3 files might have equal number of blocks 1 to block 5's and the final smaller file might have the remaining blocks 1 to block 5's.

Lets say I have five block 1 to block 5's

```
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
1hdohdsohsoihssodhoishs
2nfdksnkdsnfsdsjndkdj
3kjdscdskndskjndndsdsdsd
5
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
1hdohdsohsoihssodhoishs
2nfdksnkdsnfsdsjndkdj
3kjdscdskndskjndndsdsdsd
5
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
```

I will be generating 4 files as below

### File 1:

```
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
```

### File 2:

```
1hdohdsohsoihssodhoishs
2nfdksnkdsnfsdsjndkdj
3kjdscdskndskjndndsdsdsd
5
```

### File 3:

```
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
```

### File 4:

```
1hdohdsohsoihssodhoishs
2nfdksnkdsnfsdsjndkdj
3kjdscdskndskjndndsdsdsd
5
1weather dnsndjsdn 
2nm bdbdb bdbdbdbdnnd
3gfdu hsihdishdis
5
```

Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved using Unix scripting.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The three first files are the same.

Comment: I just copy pasted the same blocks, for the example purpose..Sorry for the confusion..Please consider having different blocks data

Comment: How do you decide to put 2 blocks in File4 (rather than, for example, having a separate File5 for the fifth block)? What are the rules you are using?

Comment: Hello Steeldriver,thanks for looking at my post... In the example the number of blocks are five, I have to split the file into 4 smaller files. so one block in each first three files and the remaining two blocks in the last file.Lets say if I have 105 Blocks in the actual file, 26 blocks in first three files and 27 blocks in the last file

Comment: Basically, the logic is to divide the number of blocks by 4, If I have 105 Blocks->105/4=26. 25, round it 26 for the first three files and then rest of the blocks come to file 4 (27)

Answer (score 0):

With grep?

```
grep -E '^1' < file_to_parse > blocks_1
grep -E '^2' < file_to_parse > blocks_2
grep -E '^3' < file_to_parse > blocks_3
grep -v -E '^1' | grep -v -E '^2' | grep -v -E '^3' < file_to_parse > other_blocks
```

Not tested.

Comment: I think I have not explained my doubt in detail, I have modified my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

OK, so - taking some input, separating it on `5` and then splitting the chunks out into separate files?

It's actually slightly harder than it sounds to put 'extra' in the last file since you have to read the whole thing *first* before you can know the distribution, but it's quite easy to round robin the output:

- Open 4 filehandles
- set record separator to `5`.
- iterate input records, selecting a file handle based on the "chunk" number `$.`
- print to that fh

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num_files_to_write = 4;
use Data::Dumper;

my @filehandles; 
for my $id ( 1..$num_files_to_write ) {
   open ( my $fh, '>', "file_$id.txt" ) or die $!;
   push @filehandles, $fh; 
}

local $/ = '5';
while ( <> ) {
    select $filehandles[$. % $num_files_to_write];
    print; 
}

foreach my $fh ( @filehandles ) { 
   close ( $fh ); 
}
```

Note - doesn't quite do the ordering you wanted, because the 'first' chunk is zero, but your first file number is 1. That's as simple as adding/subtracting from `$. + 1 % $num_files_to_write` for example. But that depends if you care exactly which file gets what, or if it's just a question of dividing up.

Comment: Thank you so much Sobrique, its just diving the file and the order is not important. I will give it a try and update you the status.Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I have tested the script, and seems like the order is not being preserved when being copied to different files. I will try to see what may be causing that.

Comment: It's alternating file outputs, because that is the only way to do it without reading the file twice.

Comment: Yes, alternate outputs should be good, but for some reason the order of blocks is being messed up. In a block I might have Block 1,2,3,2,3,2,3,5..which means each end of block is indicated by a block 5 and each block can have any number of block types.

Comment: So, basically the first block which ends with a block 5 can be in first file, the next block ending with a block 5 can be in second file like in round robin and so on

Comment: It seemed to work given your sample data,  but you should be able to debug by making use of $_ which is the current block.